# JSON Deserialize with change name field

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I need to deserialize this json:
`{ "name": { "field": "kop", "field2": false }  }`

But **"Name"** is already different, how I can do it?
For example:
one time it can be

`{ "JOHN": { "field": "kop", "field2": false }  }`

, but another time it will be another name:

`{ "BILL": { "field": "kop", "field2": false }  }` etc.

Comment: What language do you use ?  Can you show the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @Serge , C#, I don't trying anything, because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Why  is  name different?

Comment: @Serge, this is how api works.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean . Can you post 2-3 examples of your json to see what do you mean

Comment: @Serge, ok, I posted

Comment: Look at my answer you can use a dictionary for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, MyData>
```

Like this:

```
    public class MyData
    {
        [JsonProperty("field")]
        public string Field { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("field2")]
        public bool Field2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Then deserialize like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, MyData>>(jsonStringGoesHere);
```

So now the name will become the Key of the dictionary.

You need to use Newtonsoft Json.

You can get the data out like this:

```
var myData = result["JOHN"];
```

Or you can get the data like this:

```
var myData = result.Values.ToList()[0];
```

or you can get the KeyValuePair like this:

```
var keyValPair = result.FirstOrDefault();
```

Which then you can use the Key and Value properties to get both key and value.  You will need to add using System.Linq to call FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score -1):

you can use Newtonsoft.Json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

   var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json).Properties().First();

    Data data = new Data
    {
        Name = jsonParsed.Name,
        Value = jsonParsed.Value.ToObject<Item>()
    };

public partial class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Item Value { get; set; }
}

public partial class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("field")]
    public string Field { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("field2")]
    public bool Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is will not work, because "name" is changing every time. 
For example: One time it can be "JOHN", but another time it will be "ROBERT" etc.

Comment: This does not work

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro All my code is tested

Comment: This is not clear and also not a very good way to work with json using JObject.  It is better to use strongly typed models.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Just for the future. Dont  use a dictionary if you can get  without it since a dictionary is a not strongly typed model.

Comment: @Serge it is... you specify the type of the key and the type of the value.  Certainly the most common way to deal with this scenario. Since this is actually a dictionary in the JSON.